# Android HttpsUrlConnection java.io.EOFException

Tags: android, inputstream, httpsurlconnection

I have a problem where my HttpsURLConnection will throw an EOFException when i try to open this URL: http://www.weather.com.cn/data/cityinfo/101210101.html

Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.weather.com.cn/data/cityinfo/101210101.html");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
for(int n;(n = in.read(b)) != -1;){
    out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
}
```

The following is the StackTrace：

```
java.io.EOFException
    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:64)
    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readIntLe(RealBufferedSource.java:115)
    at com.android.okio.GzipSource.consumeTrailer(GzipSource.java:168)
    at com.android.okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:87)
    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:149)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:295)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
    at com.coolweather.app.coolweather.util.HttpUtil$1.run(HttpUtil.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Are you getting this issue only on Android because it is working properly as a java program?

Comment: when I open URL like these on the same domain, I didn't get this issue:
http://www.weather.com.cn/data/list3/city.xml
http://www.weather.com.cn/data/list3/city19.xml

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem too. I have fixed it by adding :

`connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "musixmatch");`

or

`connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");`

after  `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");`

Setting connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", ""); effectively fixed the issue because it doesn't wait anymore for gzipped output and so doesn't trigger a timeout.

more detail:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24672

Comment: I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may add `connection.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Encoding", "" );` after `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");` because the http response header of the url is `"Content-Encoding:gzip"`. You can see an explaination [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24672)
and another [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/itoy/p/5829231.html).